# Can't restart or stop sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: ][1]]

I want to change windows authentication to SQL Server Authentication, but I need restart connection SQL Server for change it

Comment: What happens if you try to restart it via the Configuration Manager?

Comment: You can manually restart it in servicesor SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: Alternatively, stop SQL Server from an administrator command prompt: `NET STOP MSSQLSERVER`. This will check for dependent services and stop those those too after asking for confirmation. Start the dependent services after restarting SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sql server configuration manager`

[image]

Comment: but i can't change windows authentication to sql server authentication

Comment: That has nothing to do with restarting the instance, @AlViyanBadroKamali .

Comment: @AlViyanBadroKamali through the magnifying glass in windows find `Sql server configuration manager` and restart SQL server